# Как отправить в POST-запросе JSON с набором символов $, \n, []

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, post, requests

Есть POST- запрос, с телом, в котором есть строка имеющая приблизительно такой вид:

```
"string":"somestring($name: String!, $surname: String!, $details: [item], $page: Int, $sortBy: String, $sortDesc: Boolean) {\n...}
```

как отправить корректно запрос с таким телом в Python3? видимо из за  разнообразия символов всех мастей я некорректно отправляю тело.
отправляю так (библиотека requests):

```
data = json.dumps(тело запроса строкой)
```

или пробовал так: `json.loads(тело запроса строкой)`

судя по ответу сервера, он не понял пришедший запрос:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>
```

Comment: попробуйте передать в параметре json: r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data), где data - словарь... дадите ссылку, куда вы это хотите отправить?

Comment: json=data работает! спасибо!